# Manipulate customer grid column data in csv(export)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, csv, customer-grid, customer-csv

I added a custom column in customer grid i.e subscriber_status which is showing correctly. In DB the actual value saved as either 1(subscribed) or 3(unsubscribed).

Currently I am able to manipulate data i.e 1 as YES and 3 as NO text which 
I am displaying in my custom column but when I am exporting CSV data is displaying as 1 or 3 .

But I want it to show either **YES** or **NO** in **CSV**.